# Unknown background green lines in React downloaded image?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, png

I'm using the below code to download screenshots of my application:

```
download = filename => {
            const a = document.createElement('a');
            a.download = filename;
            getDownloadURL().then(url => {
              a.href = url;
              document.body.appendChild(a);
              a.click();
              a.remove();
            });
        };

getDownloadURL = async () => {
          const svg = document.querySelector('#widget svg'),
            canvas = new OffscreenCanvas(svg.clientWidth * 3, svg.clientHeight * 3),
            svgString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg),
            ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
            v = await Canvg.fromString(ctx, svgString, presets.offscreen());

          await v.render();
          const blob = await canvas.convertToBlob(),
            pngUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

          return pngUrl;
        },
```

The downloaded image has few unknown green lines at the background, what are these?

And how can these be removed?

[image]

This element appears fine in the application without these unknown lines.

Comment: What's the image? Please add a [mcve] of it to the question i.e. as markup.

Comment: For what it's worth, this code works fine if you initialize OffscreenCanvas to (0, 0) and then set svgString to the text contents of the [Wikimedia test.svg file](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bd/Test.svg). The resulting png file has no lines in it.  My guess is that the problem is coming from serializeToString on the widget node, or possibly there's a problem with your specific SVG file.  In any case, I think at present your question doesn't have enough information to answer it.  Knowing what '#widget svg' is might help?